# Doubts on player movement strategy

Tags: 2d, movement, path-finding

What I want to achieve is the player moving to the touched position on a 2D grid-based game, stopping at the last reachable spot if the target position is unreachable. What is the strategy usually adopted in these cases? Should I implement a specific path finding algorithm for the player?

Comment: Not sure if there is a usual case which would fit all methods of getting something from point A to point B. It all depends really. for example,  an implementation of A* could get you to the closest spot.

tutorial here
http://www.policyalmanac.org/games/aStarTutorial.htm

Comment: I was already thinking of an A* algorithm -for each node, calculate the distance to the target from the four nodes around, then move to the closest non obstructed of these nodes and repeat- but my main doubt was: If the target is unreachable (say the target is in the water and the player is already near the river) who tells the player to stop there and not continuosly move up and down the river on the two closest non-obstructed nodes?

Comment: Is the target unreachable due to changes after the path was found or was it unreachable at the beginning?

Comment: At the beginning

Comment: But I want to move 'till the latest disponible node, not to don't move at all.

Comment: First thing that springs to mind is to use the a* cell movement cost. So your grid tiles that you cant reach have a max movement cost. This way the a* will still calculate the path, but as you move you dont allow moving onto max-cost tiles.
Make sense?

Comment: Totally. But isn't there a way to implement a real time version of the a* algorithm, instead of precalculating the path at the start?

Comment: if your grid changes I guess you only have to recalculate it. What you can do to save performance is to calculate a* on a subset of the grid, say 10 cells from a given one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to achieve partial pathfinding?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/82690/how-to-achieve-partial-pathfinding)

Answer (score 2):

This [question on partial path-finding](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/82690/how-to-achieve-partial-pathfinding) presents one solution - modify your path finding algorithm to remember the node visited that had the closest estimated distance to the target. Eventually, the path-finding will fail to get a route to the target (since it was unreachable), but you will have a path to the closest point encountered while it searched.